# How can I use ODE events in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, ode

I need to have a better understanding about how to define ODE events.
What I know is that if I have my ODE defined as

```
[t,q,te,qe,ie] = ode45(odefun,tspan,q0(:,1),options);
options = odeset('Events',@events);
function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,q)
    value = ...; 
    isterminal = ...; 
    direction = ...; 
end
```

I need to define the `value` as a function of `q` and `t`in such a way that it goes to zero. So, for example, if I want to find when `v = 0` I just need to write

```
value = q(2);
isterminal = 1;
direction = 0;
```

But is writing

```
value = [q(2),q(2)];
isterminal = [1,1];
direction = [1,-1];
```

equivalent to the previous formulation?

And what if I want to stop the integration when `q(2) < toll`? I mean, is it possible to stop the integration if `q(2)` is very close to xero but not exactly zero? (I am thinking about something like the Karnopp model used to model the sticking condition in this picture http://vibrationacoustics.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/data/journals/jvacek/28878/s_011506vaj1.jpeg)

Also, in the vector `te` and `qe` I have the time instants and the solution values when the events are encountered. If I have 2 different events to be satisfied (lets call them type 1 and type 2) but I want to plot only the events of type 1, how can I tell Matlab?

Finally, what checks can I perform to be sure the ODE correctly identifies all the events?

Comment: For Matlab-specific advice, you might consider asking your question at [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral) (in the Newsgroup or Answers sections).